# Hardhat/Waffle/Chai : Display Revert Reason?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, waffle, chai

I'm testing a simple call and expect it to not revert

```
await expect(swapCall).to.not.be.reverted
```

The test fails currently and I get a

```
AssertionError: Expected transaction NOT to be reverted
```

How do I get hardhat / waffle / chai to display the revert reason?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try using `await expect(swapCall).revertedWith('revertMessage')`

Comment: Doesn't work with `not.be.revertedWith` and the test will pass since the tx did _not_ revert with a known message but with some other revert msg/reason.

Comment: You wanted to display the revert reason, I've shown you how to do it, by putting an arbitrary string in the expected message that is different from the actual one.

Comment: Or if you're using hardhat, the console.log is very helpful for debugging in such cases